# What is the most efficient way to select an XML value based on one of its associative attributes using C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML document that resembles this:

```
<resorts>
    <resort location="locationA" email="locationA@somewhere.com"></resort>
    <resort location="locationB" email="locationB@somewhere.com"></resort>
    <resort location="locationC" email="locationC@somewhere.com"></resort>
    <resort location="locationD" email="locationD@somewhere.com"></resort>
</resorts>
```

I need to get the corresponding email address given a specific location and the code I'm using to do that is:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(xml);
    XmlElement xmlRoot = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xmlRoot.SelectNodes("/resorts/resort");

    foreach(XmlNode element in xmlNodes)
            {
                foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in element.Attributes)
                {
                    switch (attribute.Name)
                    {
                        case "location":
                            if (attribute.Value.ToLower() == location.ToLower())
                            {
                                loc = attribute.Value;
                                locationIdentified = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "email":
                            if (locationIdentified)
                            {
                                if(!emailIdentified)
                                { 
                                    email = attribute.Value;
                                    var recipientList = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "emailrecipients", email } };
                                    emailRecipients.Add(recipientList);
                                    emailIdentified = true;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
           }
return recipients;
```

But I don't really care much for the iterative approach and would prefer something more streamlined with less code.

Something similar to a linq expression would be ideal but I don't typically have to deal much with XML data so I'm a bit of a novice in this area; but I know there has to be a better way to get retrieve the data from the XML.

What I need to do is acquire the email address for a specific location; having the location known beforehand.

What would be the most efficient manner to do this without an explicit iteration as I've done here?

This question is not specifically about "**how to use**" alternative options as much as "**what are more streamlined approaches**" to solve this problem. However, as I stated; since I am a novice at XML, it would be nice to have examples of any proposed alternatives

Thanks

Comment: Just use xpath, select the element that has the attribute you want and take the attribute value. E.g. to get the location attribute just use `resorts/resort/@location`, you can find sibling elements/attributes too, give me a sec (on my mobile!)

Comment: Thanks but could you provide a small example leveraging C#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518096/xpath-to-select-value-of-sibling-attribute-with-namespace here's a good example, the accepted answer, you can basically select an element and use square brackets to indicate a condition on the current element without actually selecting deeper into the xml tree.

Comment: E.g. `resorts/resort[@location='locationA']/@email`. I'm sure you could also grab the whole set but I believe you are still going to need to iterate to put into a list, it's just more terse code (which is what we want!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xpath to select value of sibling attribute with namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518096/xpath-to-select-value-of-sibling-attribute-with-namespace)

Comment: @Juan I wouldn't consider my question to be a duplicate since the post you reference is explicitly asking how to use Xpath to select the value of a sibling attribute. My question implied no explicit reference to XPath, I asked for potential alternatives to my problem which didn't explicitly state Xpath as an answer.

Comment: @Mark: That is why it says "possible duplicate", not "definitely a duplicate". You still accepted the same answer as the original post so... :-)

Comment: @Juan: okay, got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

octavioccl's answer is correct, but if you have some reason to stick with `XmlDocument` rather than switching to Linq to XML (perhaps this is a large project that's already heavily committed to the old XML classes, and nobody wants to cross the streams), this will work:

```
string location = "locationC";

string xpath = "/resorts/resort[@location='" + location + "']/@email";

var address = doc.SelectNodes(xpath).Cast<XmlAttribute>()
              .Select(attr => attr.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

If you can use C#6 features, this is tidier:

```
var address = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath)?.Value;
```

If you need it to be case-blind, I think you may be stuck with this:

```
string xpath = "/resorts/resort[translate(@location, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='" 
              + location.ToLower() + "']/@email";
```

There's a `lower-case()` function in XPath 2.0, but `SelectNodes` seems to be implementing XPath 1.0. That messy `translate()` call is the usual workaround.

Comment: Perfect and on point, "this is a large project that's already heavily committed to the old XML"

Comment: @Mark I'm still trying to figure out how to make it case-blind, though.

Comment: @Mark Case-blindness achieved.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Linq to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) your query could be like this:

```
var query=root.Descendants("resort").Where(e=>e.Attribute("location").Value.ToLower()==location.ToLower())
                                    .Select(e=>e.Attribute("email"));
```

If there is only one with that location you can use `FirstOrDefault` extension method to get it:

```
var result=query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately the code is not configured to use Linq to XML. I will use that class moving forward. At least I am more familiar with the Linq expressions also

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say what is most efficient, but you could look into using XPath to traverse XML without having to iterate.

Here are some examples of what that looks like:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx